# When an element is focused, on press of a key, trigger a CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make this site more accessible by adding keyboard navigation and actions.

What I'm trying to do is on focus, by tabbing, of a member of the `.dataCard` class and then on press of certain keys, trigger certain css animations.

- On press of left arrow key, trigger the `.left` class addition and animation
- On press of right arrow key or delete, trigger `.right` class addition and animation

Here is my code, why isn't it working?

```
$('.dataCard').focus(function(){
    $(this).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.target === this){
            if(event.which === '37'){
                $('.dataCard').not('.focused, .greeting, .spelling').addClass('animated').addClass('left');
            }
            else if(event.which === '39' || event.which === '46'){
                $('.dataCard').not('.focused, .greeting, .spelling').addClass('animated').addClass('right');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can u please create a fiddle.

Comment: @AamirAfridi I figured it out. Answering my question.

Comment: Fiddle please,unless, we cannote accurate the issue

Answer (score 0):

When checking for which key is pressed, don't use strings, the key-code is an int.

```
if(event.which === 37)
```

Comment: or if you do use a string, make sure you use just two `==` signs. As this will coerce the values to the same type before comparing them